# cp doesn't work in a script but does from the command line

Tags: bash, scripting, cp

I have this script for automating a simple process where I scan a number into the command line, grep that number out of a catalog file which gives me a path, and then copy the DVD which the above mentioned number corresponds to, to the path.   The cp command keeps failing.  I've looked at other posts where cp is not working in a script but they all seem to have to do with quotes around filenames.  I don't think that's my problem here.

I've added some comments for I hope will turn out to be clarity:

```
\#!/bin/bash
\# accepts a single command line parameter:  six-digit DVD number, ex. 987110
\# the empty echo lines are just whitespace for readability**

clear

file=/public/TAPES/batch1/Shipment_1_catalog.txt.dvd

echo
echo DVD number is       $1

echo
echo catalogfile is      $file

>\# this grep instruction greps $1 out of $file
>\# output from this is 'XXXXXX file-path-to-copy-dvd-contents-to'
>\# qwk puts the file-path... into $pth

pth=`grep $1 $file | awk ' { print $2 } '`

echo

echo destination path is $pth

echo

mount /dev/sr0 /media     # appears to work

cp -p -r /media/\* $pth   # this always fails - see error text below.

echo

umount /dev/sr0 && eject  # this does work
```

Everything works except the copy command.  It produces the following error output:

> DVD number is 987110

```
catalogfile is /public/TAPES/batch1/Shipment_1_catalog.txt.dvd

destination path is > /proj/T_010/gdm/SAM/BRA/3D/Santos_ESP_3D_BDEP_2010/dvd/legacy/987110_Line_Section_Various_Vintages-Post_Stack_Migration_DVD_14_of_41

mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
cp: cannot stat `/media/*': No such file or directory
```

The permissions for the script are 755.  I've tried it as './cpy.sh' and 'bash cpy.sh' with the same results both times.

Comment: put a `sleep 10` between `mount` and `cp` command lines. When you mount a DVD it takes a few seconds to discover the contents.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `*`?  Do you really want to find a file named `*` and not use it as a glob?

Comment: @MelBurslan - sleep 10 doesn't seem to help.  I still get the 'cp: cannot stat `/media/*` ...`  message.

Comment: @EricRenouf; un-escaping the * seems to have helped.  The cp command proceeds but now gives me a "cp: failed to preserve ownership for blah blah blah,  :  Operation not permitted"

Comment: @EricRenouf;  it looks like somehow the '-p' switch for the cp command isn't working.

Comment: @dwesson are you running the script as root?  If not you might lack permission to do the preserve ownership part.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/193898/preserve-permission-switch-not-working-with-cp for example

Comment: is that a typo where it says "destination path is > /proj..." - because your corresponding echo command does not have the greater-than sign

Comment: Eric Renouf answered for you, you are trying to copy a file called literally /media/* which doesnt exist.  you probably want all the things under media copied, so use rsync -apvz /media/ "$pth"

Comment: You need to run this as root to preserve another users permissions if you dont own all the files.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments.  They're really helped me clarify my thoughts.  I have not been running the script as root and haven't tried rsync either.   Those are the next two things to try...

Answer (score 1):

On UNIX systems wildcards are handled by the shell. The escaped `*` in the following command is passed to `cp` which looks a file named `/media/*` and presumably that doesn't exist.

```
cp -p -r /media/\* $pth
```

In Windows, by contrast, the `*` is not handled by the command processor but by the `copy` command.

Only root is allowed to change file ownership. Otherwise, any user of the system will be able take any other users files. So `cp: failed to preserve ownership ...` is expected.